# Center <th> in bootstrap in double header table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello i have a table and i want to center a th between two other th.
I want to change the position of th **Vieillesse de base** to be displayed in the center of **Provisionnel** and **Régularisation**.

Here my HTML :

```html
<div class="row mt-1">
   <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-striped table-adjust ">
         <thead class="cordonnes-cabinet">
            <tr>
               <th scope="col">Date</th>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:center" colspan="2">Vieillesse de base</th>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:right">Complémentaire</th>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:right">Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th scope="col">...</th>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:right">Provisionnel</th>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:right">Régularisation</th>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:right">...</th>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:right">...</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody class="cordonnes-cabinet">
            @for (int i = 0; i < echeancierGeneriqueAjustee.Count; i++)
            {
            <tr>
               <th style="font-weight:100">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[i]["Date"])</th>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[i]["MontantProv"])</td>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[i]["MontantRegul"])</td>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[i]["MontantComplement"])</td>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[i]["TotalEcheance"])</td>
            </tr>
            }
            <tr>
               <th style="font-size:14px">Total</th>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[0]["TotalProv"])</td>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[0]["TotalRegul"])</td>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[0]["TotalComplement"])</td>
               <td style="text-align:right">@(echeancierGeneriqueAjustee[0]["Total"])</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting it centred to the gap between the two headings? if so you cannot do that with css - you would need some js to calculate the width of that space and then centre it to that width

Comment: Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/p1n7wu3x/3 it needs the table layout to be fixed and widths assigned to the columns

Comment: @Pete i don't want to use js

Comment: Then you cannot do this and the best you can do is to left align the provisional title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to do this is use html `colspan` in the `th`, to simulate equality of width with the second row. Then you only need to use `.text-center`.

In you particular case, use `colspan="2"` in the second `th`

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ycsbog4n/)

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="cordonnes-cabinet">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Vieillesse de base</th>
      <th>Complémentaire</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:10%">...</th>
      <th class="text-center">Provisionnel</th>
      <th class="text-center">Régularisation</th>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbbody>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <td class="text-center">col2</td>
      <td class="text-center">col3</td>
      <td>col4</td>
      <td>col5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that your text is centered but the Column to the right is X wide and creates a optical illusion that your column is a lot wider.

I would set the column saying "Complémentaire" to `text-align: left` with class `text-left` then it will create the illuion you want.

Ive attached a picture where you can see that your code actually centers the text its just an optical illuion[image]

This is how it would look with left aligned in the blue column:
[image]

And now its just a question on how to make it pretier with paddings on the td's and th's

Comment: so how can i prevent this optical illuion you said the column to the right x cause the optical illusion

Comment: so now how can i make it pretier ?

Comment: I would add some paddings to the th's as a quick example: https://jsbin.com/yutixasuwa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: for me it is not working correctly again maybe th cause the css !?